# Multiple periods under single For Statement

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

Im looking at running a For loop for a number of rows and columns, however I am skipping some columns.

So ATM my code resembles this, however this does not work. How can I express this range of columns whilst also not including the columns I do not need.

```
For irow = DateStart To DateEnd

For icolumn = 32 To 40
For icolumn = 43 To 58
For icolumn = 60 To 61
For icolumn = 63 To 67
```

Thanks in advance

```
Sub Button16_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Drill As String
Dim postRow As Integer
Dim irow As Integer
Dim icolumn As Integer
Dim DateStart As Integer
Dim DateEnd As Integer
Dim SheetDate As Date


 'Start Date and End Date Row from Drill Data entry Sheet
 DateStart = Sheet16.Cells(4, 9).Value
 DateEnd = Sheet16.Cells(5, 9).Value

postRow = 9 ' posting in Uploadsheet
Sheet1.Select


'Drill1 = Range("C16")



For irow = DateStart To DateEnd
For icolumn = 32 To 40
For icolumn = 43 To 58
For icolumn = 60 To 61
For icolumn = 63 To 67




      If Cells(irow, icolumn) > 0.01 Then
    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 1) = "A"
    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 2) = Format(Sheet1.Cells(irow, 2), "yyyymmdd") 'Shift Date
    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 3) = Sheet1.Cells(irow, 4) 'Shift NS/DS
    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 4) = Sheet1.Cells(irow, 3) 'equipment type
    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 5) = Sheet1.Cells(4, icolumn) 'code Type
    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(irow, icolumn) 'Hours for code type

    postRow = postRow + 1
    Else
      End If
    Next
  Next



Sheets("UploadSheet").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a discontiguous range and use the column index ordinals.

```
Dim c As Range
With Range("AF:AN, AQ:BF, BH:BI, BK:BO")
    For Each c In .Columns
        Debug.Print c.Column
    Next c
End With

' 32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  60  61  63  64  65  66  67
```

Put this into your code something like this.

```
Dim c As Range, iRow As Long, iColumn As Long
Dim postRow As Long, DateStart As Long, DateEnd As Long

'stuff for postRow, DateStart & DateEnd here

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For iRow = DateStart To DateEnd
        With Range("AF:AN, AQ:BF, BH:BI, BK:BO")
            For Each c In .Columns
                iColumn = c.Column
                If Cells(iRow, iColumn) > 0.01 Then
                    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 1) = "A"
                    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 2) = Format(.Cells(iRow, 2), "yyyymmdd") 'Shift Date
                    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 3) = .Cells(iRow, 4) 'Shift NS/DS
                    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 4) = .Cells(iRow, 3) 'equipment type
                    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 5) = .Cells(4, iColumn) 'code Type
                    Sheets("UploadSheet").Cells(postRow, 6) = .Cells(iRow, iColumn) 'Hours for code type
                    postRow = postRow + 1
                End If
            Next c
        End With
    Next iRow
End With
```

Comment: Sorry Im still very new with VBA. How would that work with the rest of my code

Comment: I left the code widely generic because I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with the columns once you located them. Perhaps you could edit your question to include on the operation(s) to be performed on each column.

Comment: Ive put in the Rest of my code.

It basically scans through a sheet and collects output, however it needs to skip over selected columns that are not needed, that would return values which would be errors

Comment: I'm not sure if there will be some redundancy but I put the non-contiguous loop in where I thought it was most appropriate.

Comment: Hmmm no luck not getting any output. Thanks for the help though!